# Django [WinError 5] IIS

Tags: python, django, windows, iis, urlopen

I have a problem with Django 1.11 on Windows IIS. On localhost it works, but on IIS not. Any ideas?

Error [WinError 5] Access denied
http://www.wklej.org/id/3223563/

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from . models import Order

import sqlite3
import time
import datetime

import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import urllib.request as ur

def get_order(request):
web_data = ur.urlopen('http://www.xxxx.com/pl/pl/xml/index/id/xxxx/password/xxxxx/no_tagging/1')
str_data = web_data.read()
xml_data = et.fromstring(str_data)
order_list = xml_data.findall("order")
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
c = conn.cursor()
for order in order_list:
    order_id = order.find("bestellungid").text
    add_date = order.find("datum").text
    amount = order.find("anzahl").text
    price = order.find("a_preis_a").text
    desc = order.find("a_bezeichnung1").text
    sap = order.find("a_int_artikelid").text
    customer_name = order.find("h_name1").text
    customer_street = order.find("h_anschrift").text
    customer_code = order.find("h_plz").text
    customer_city = order.find("h_ort").text
    customer_phone = order.find("h_telefon").text
    payment = 'Pobranie'
    status = 'Nie zrealizowane'

    c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tyre24_order (order_id, add_date, amount, price, desc, sap, customer_name, customer_street, customer_code, customer_city, customer_phone, payment, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (order_id, add_date, amount, price, desc, sap, customer_name, customer_street, customer_code, customer_city, customer_phone, payment, status))

conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
return render(request, 'get_tyre.html')
```

Comment: Please post the traceback as string, not as an image.

Comment: From your barely readable capture of the traceback, the problem is the with the `urllib.urlopen()` call.

Comment: Also (totally unrelated but) : you definitely DONT want to writre anything to your database on a GET request - GET requests are supposed to be idempotent (=> they should not change the server state).

Comment: traceback: http://www.wklej.org/id/3223563/

Comment: So ? Can't you read the traceback ? Have you tried searching for "WinError 5" ?  The user your IIS process is running under doesn't seem to have the permissions (OS level permissions I mean) to access local SSL certificates.

Comment: Do you mean something like that?

http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2012/02/grant-iis-75-access-to-certificate-in.html

Comment: Possibly yes, but I can't really tell, the last Windows version I used was NT4 xD

Comment: It works. 
I use this [link](https://www.gigaone.pl/wsparcie-techniczne/instalacja-certyfikatu-ssl/iis-7)
and change urllib to requests

http://wklej.org/id/3224059/

Comment: Well you may want to answer the question yourself then so someone else having the same problem will know how to solve it. Oh and yes please edit your question to include the full traceback.